# count(*) records grouped by date across two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, union

I've got two tables:

**emailLog** table:

```
email           sendTime                   sourceTag
-------------------------------------------------------
yadda@aol.com   2016-11-17 09:14:37.213    WelcomeEmail
badda@aol.com   2016-11-16 09:14:37.213    WelcomeEmail
test@aol.com    2016-11-15 09:12:33.213    WelcomeEmail
```

**registrations** table:

```
email           dateRegistered             regSource
-------------------------------------------------------
yadda@aol.com   2016-11-17 09:14:37.213    WelcomeEmail
badda@aol.com   2016-11-16 09:14:37.213    WelcomeEmail
test@aol.com    2016-11-15 09:12:33.213    WelcomeEmail
```

I'm trying to do a combined query to show the COUNT() of people who received an email on a given date compared with the COUNT() of people who have registered on a given date

I have gotten as far as this:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(10), sendTime, 120) as date,
    COUNT(*) as numberSent 
    FROM emailLog
WHERE sourceTag = 'WelcomeEmail'
AND
sendTime BETWEEN '20161110' and '20161120'
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(varchar(10), sendTime, 120)
ORDER BY DATE ASC;
```

Which gives me a list of the emails sent with a specific sourceTag, grouped by the date:

```
DATE                NUMBERSENT
2016-11-17          256
2016-11-18          136
2016-11-19          40
2016-11-20          118
2016-11-21          186
```

But I can't figure out how to join a sum of the registrations for that date + with that source, like:

```
DATE                NUMBERSENT    MEMBERSREGISTERED
2016-11-17          256           12
2016-11-18          136           24
2016-11-19          40            13
2016-11-20          118           2
2016-11-21          186           11
```

I have tried to do something like...

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT count(*) from emailLog) 
    as emailLogResults, 
 (select count(*) from registrations) 
    as registrationResults
    ...
```

but I am stuck after that. Any help very much appreciated

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple and clear, i think, you can create 2 temporary tables. The first one will contain the list of the emails sent with a specific sourceTag, grouped by the date, as you already did. And the second table will do the same thing for the registrations. You can than inner join the 2 temporary tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `full join` (to get rows from the other table when are no rows for a specific date in either of the tables) with the two tables and then use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(10), e.sendTime, 120),CONVERT(varchar(10), r.dateRegistered, 120)) as date,
    COUNT(e.email) as numberSent,
    COUNT(r.email) as membersRegistered
FROM emailLog e
FULL JOIN registrations r ON e.sendTime = r.dateRegistered
AND e.sourceTag = 'WelcomeEmail'
AND r.regSource = 'WelcomeEmail'
AND e.sendTime BETWEEN '20161110' and '20161120' 
AND r.dateRegistered BETWEEN '20161110' and '20161120'
GROUP BY COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(10), e.sendTime, 120),CONVERT(varchar(10), r.dateRegistered, 120))
ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

Comment: I thought of this too, but you are basing the date on the `emailLog`. What if there are registrations on a specific date with no emails?

Comment: @WEI_DBA .. there is a date filter for registrations as well.

Comment: Yup... guess I'm thinking at a broader sense. :-)